# How to use underscorejs to manipulate a DOM element's attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I know underscorejs template is way more useful to replace some sort of string. But can I use the same template mechanism to manipulate a DOM's attribute values based on an action?

Let's say I've a table (kendogrid) and I want to change a row's background color dynamically (a dropdown menu will be shown to the end user). I used jQuery to change the background. But my boss is insisting me to use underscorejs's template. I'm kinda stuck.

Help?? Anyone??

Comment: Are you trying to manipulate the DOM by re-rendering and inserting the template?  You could manipulate the DOM via native Javascript if you're avoiding the use of jQuery.

Comment: The thing is that I've no idea how to use underscorejs to implement this function. Like I said, it's my boss's intention to use underscorejs. If it were plain javascript, I would've completed this a long time ago. ;)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that they want you to update the data and render the template everytime there is an event that changes the DOM state.

HTML:

```
<div id="container"></div>
<select id="highlight-choice">
    <option value="0">first</option>
    <option value="1" selected>second</option>
</select>

<script id="gridtemplate" type="text/template">
    <table id="kendogrid">
        <% _.each(rows, function(row) { %>
            <tr style="background: <%= row.background %>;">
                <% _.each(row.columns, function(column) { %>
                    <td><%= column %><td>
                <% });%>
            </tr>
        <% }); %>
    </table>
</script>
```

Javascript: (certain parts must be run after DOM is ready)

```
var compile = _.template(document.getElementById('gridtemplate').innerHTML);

var data = {
    rows: [
        {
            columns: [1,2],
            background: '#fff'
        },
        {
            columns: [3,4],
            background: '#ff0'
        }
    ]
};

function render() {
    document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = compile(data);
}

render();

document.getElementById('highlight-choice').addEventListener('change', function() {
    _.each(data.rows, function(row) {
        row.background = '#fff';
    });
    data.rows[this.value].background = '#ff0';
    render();
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wio_dude/fo7oxdtq/)

Comment: thanks. But I'm using a kendogrid. I don't know how to add underscore template to a kendo rowtemplate. Can you give me an example using a kendogrid?

Comment: Something like   var row = _.template($(tr + "[" + dataUid + "='" + uid + "']").css('background-color',<%= empty %>));
var c = dataItem.Color == whiteStyle ? '' : dataItem.Color;
row({ empty: c });